# How to check if Google AdSense working correctly in my ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, adsense

I have an ASP.NET website that contains some Google AdSense, and I wondered if it's possible to check programmatically whether that ads works correctly or not!

If it's possible, how to do that in VB.NET (Or C#)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a script using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to automatically load your Web application in a browser and inspect the DOM to ensure the Google Ad is appearing correctly. Selenium supports C#.